# Prove that all the tangents of a function do not touch a given point

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

A quick question that I'm stuck on:

> Prove that the point $(2,1)$ does not touch any of the tangent lines of 
>   $f(x)= x^2 - 4x$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In general, if $K$ is a convex subset of $\Bbb R^2$ whose boundary $\partial K$ is a differentiable curve, then the set of points not on any tangent of $\partial K$ contains the interior of $K$.  In this problem, $K$ can be taken to be the convex set $$\big\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\big| y\ge x^2-4x\big\}.$$  Then the interior of $K$ is the set $$\big\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\big| y > x^2-4x\big\}.$$   The point $(2,1)$ lies in the interior of $K$, and therefore it is not on any tangent to the boundary of $K$, which is just the parabola  $$\big\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\big| y = x^2-4x\big\}.$$

Comment: I would like to note that the set $S(K)$ of points not on any tangent of $\partial K$ can contain more than the interior $K^\circ$ of $K$.  In the example above (i.e., in the OP's question), it does hold that $S(K)=K^\circ$.  However, if $K$ is the convex set $$\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\big|x>0\wedge xy\geq 1\big\},$$ then $$S(K)=K^\circ \cup \overline{Q}_{--},$$ where $\overline{Q}_{--}$ is the closure of the third quadrant.  That is, $$K^\circ=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\big|x>0\wedge xy> 1\big\}$$ and $$\overline{Q}_{--}=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\big|x\le 0\wedge y\le 0\big\}.$$

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=c$ is given by
$$y_c=f'(c)(x-c)+f(c)=(2c-4)x-c^2.$$

Suppose, for some $c$, this line contains $(2,1)$. Then $1=(2c-4)2-c^2$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
we want to show that
the tangent to the curve
is below the curve.
Since your point is above
$(2, f(2))
=(2, 0)$,
all the tangents
will be below it.

The tangent at
$(a, f(a))$
is
$y
= f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)
$.

Putting in
$x=b, y=f(b)$,
we want to show that
when $b \ne a$
we have
$f(b)
\gt f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)
$
or
$f(b)- f(a)
\gt f'(a)(b-a)
$.

If
$f(x)
=x^2-4x
$,
$f'(x) = 2x-4
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(b)-f(a)
&=b^2-4b-(a^2-4a)\\
&=b^2-a^2-4(b-a)\\
&=(b-a)(b+a-4)\\
\end{array}
$

and
$(b-a)f'(a)
=(2a-4)(b-a)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(a)
&=(b-a)(b+a-4)-(b-a)(2a-4)\\
&=(b-a)(b+a-2a)\\
&=(b-a)^2\\
&\gt 0\\
\end{array}
$

Note that this holds
for any
$f(x)
=x^2+ux+v$.

You can also show that
$f''(x) > 0$
implies that
$f(b)-f(a)
\gt (b-a)f'(a)
$.

Answer (score 0):

Any line through the point $(2,1)$ has an equation of the form $ax+by=2a+b$ for $a$ and $b$ not both $0$. If this is tangent to the parabola, then the coefficients $a$ and $b$ satisfy the dual conic equation $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-2a-b\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\0&0&-\frac12\\-2&-\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\-2a-b\end{bmatrix} = a^2+20b^2 = 0.$$ The only real solution is $a=b=0$, therefore no line through $(2,1)$ is tangent to the parabola.