# If $f''(x) > 0$ show that the tangents to $f$ are below $f$ except where they touch the curve

Tags: derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis

I'm sure that this has been here before,
but it didn't come up
when I entered the title.

This was inspired by
[Prove that all the tangents of a function do not touch a given point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514928/prove-that-all-the-tangents-of-a-function-do-not-touch-a-given-point)

Here is my proof.
I'm hoping for a simpler one.

Suppose
$f''(x) > 0$.
Show that the tangent to $f$
is below the curve.

Formally.

The tangent at
$(a, f(a))$
is
$y
= f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)
$.

Putting in
$x=b, y=f(b)$,
we want to show that
when $b \ne a$
we have
$f(b)
\gt f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)
$
or
$f(b)- f(a)
\gt f'(a)(b-a)
$.

Suppose $b > a$.
Then,
if $a < x < b$,
$f'(x)
=f'(a)+\int_a^x f''(t) dt
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
f(b)-f(a)
&=\int_a^b f'(x) dx\\
&=\int_a^b (f'(a)+\int_a^x f''(t) dt) dx\\
&=\int_a^b f'(a)dx+\int_a^b \int_a^x f''(t) dt dx\\
&=(b-a) f'(a)+\int_a^b \int_a^x f''(t) dt dx\\
&\gt(b-a) f'(a)
\qquad\text{since }
\int_a^b \int_a^x f''(t) dt dx > 0
\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
suppose $b < a$.

(This took a little work to get right.)

If $b < x < a$ then

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=f'(b)+\int_b^x f''(t) dt\\
&=f'(b)+\int_b^a f''(t) dt-\int_x^a f''(t) dt\\
&=f'(b)+(f'(a)-f'(b)-\int_x^a f''(t) dt\\
&=f'(a)-\int_x^a f''(t) dt\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
f(a)-f(b)
&=\int_b^a f'(x) dx\\
&=\int_b^a (f'(a)-\int_x^a f''(t) dt) dx\\
&=\int_b^a f'(a)dx-\int_b^a \int_x^a f''(t) dt dx\\
&=(a-b)f'(a)-\int_b^a \int_x^a f''(t) dt dx\\
&<(a-b)f'(a)
\qquad\text{since }\int_b^a \int_x^a f''(t) dt dx > 0\\
\text{or}\\
f(b)-f(a)
&>(b-a)f'(a)
\end{array}
$

Note that this same proof
shows that
if $f''(x) < 0$
then
the tangent is
above the curve
or
$f(b)-f(a)
\lt (b-a)f'(a)
$.

Comment: Isn't that an immediate consequence of Taylor's theorem? $f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)f'(a) + \frac 12 f''(\xi) (x-a)^2$.

Comment: You might need to sharpen the problem statement a bit.  Perhaps "$f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$" or "is below the curve in an open neighborhood of $x$".  The cubic, $x^3 - 3x^2 - x + 3$ has $f''(x) > 0$ for $x > 1$, but the horizontal tangent at $x = (1/3)(3+2\sqrt{3})$ passes below the graph in a neighborhood of that $x$, but intersects the graph at $x = (1/3)(3-4\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x)=f(x)-f(a)-(x-a)f'(a)$, then $\varphi'(x)=f'(x)-f'(a)$ and $\varphi''(x)=f''(x)>0$, thus $\varphi'$ is a strictly non decreasing function. But $\varphi'(a)=0$, thus $\varphi'(x)>0$ for $x>a$ and $\varphi'(x)<0$ for $x<a$. By the same argument, $\varphi(x)>\varphi(a)=0$ for all $x\neq a$.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I wanted.